# std::vector::push_back parameter by reference

Tags: c++, stl, parameters, reference, std

Consider the following source code in C++

```
vector <char *> myFunction()
{
    vector <char *> vRetVal;
    char *szSomething = new char[7];

    strcpy(szSomething,"Hello!");
    vRetVal.push_back(szSomething); // here vRetVal[0] address == &szSomething

    delete[] szSomething; // delete[]ing szSomething will "corrupt" vRetVal[0]
    szSomething = NULL;

    return vRetVal; // here i return a "corrupted" vRetVal
}
```

Any idea on how to use push_back to make a copy of the parameter I pass instead of taking it by reference? Any other idea is also accepted and appreciated.

Comment: Use `std::string`.

Comment: Why do you delete `szSomething` if you want to keep it alive?

Comment: Fail manual memory management is fail, as always.

Comment: Do you **need** to use Hungarian notation? http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object whose pointer you've pushed to the vector is destroyed by `delete` statement in your code. That means, the item (which is pointer) in the vector is pointing to a deleted object. I'm sure you don't want that.

Use `std::string`:

```
std::vector<std::string> myFunction()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("Hello"); 
    v.push_back("World");
    return v;
}
```

In C++11, you could just write this:

```
std::vector<std::string> myFunction()
{
   std::vector<std::string> v{"Hello", "World"};
   return v;
}
```

Or this,

```
std::vector<std::string> myFunction()
{
   return {"Hello", "World"};
}
```

Comment: Or `return { "Hello" };` :-)

Answer (score 3):

`push_back` *will* make a copy of the parameter you pass.

But your parameter is the pointer, not the string itself.

To automatically copy the string, use `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

push_back() *does* make a copy.  In your posted code, you're passing a pointer to a null terminated string so C++ makes a copy *of the pointer*.  If want a copy of that string, you have some options:

If you insist on using C style null terminated character arrays as strings, you can simply pass in the pointer and *not* call delete[].  Of course, since C++ has only manual memory management, you must be sure to call delete[] at a later but appropriate time...

The other option, as everyone else will tell you, is to simply use std::string.  It will manage memory for you and will mostly "just work..."

Answer (score 1):

Fail manual memory management is fail- as it always is. Use `std::string` like a sane person and you will discover that your program actually has a chance in hell of functioning correctly.